# Where to place the javascript file to relate it with a particular view folder in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my app/views/phrases/_forms.html.erb, I have a button with an id which I want to show or hide a particular section with id preview-section.

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'button', class: "btn btn-default", id: 'preview-button') do %>
    Preview
<% end %>

<section id="preview-section"> Some Content </section>
```

I'm not sure where to place the jquery in the rails app.

```
$('#preview-button').click(function () {
    alert("Preview button was clicked");
});
```

Comment: Can you show the `application.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can add this code in custom js file also:-

```
# app/assets/javascripts/custom.js
$(document).on('click', '#preview-button', function(){
    alert("Preview button was clicked");
});
```

include custom.js in application.js file:-

```
//= require custom.js
or
//= require_tree .(It will includes all js files in javascripts folder)
```

2) You can make a folder with name phrases in javascripts folder and make js file inside /app/assets/javascripts/phrases, then require this folder in application like:-

```
//= require_tree ./phrases (requires all js files in phrases folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

`app/assets/javascripts/phrases/`, it should be Rails style.

All js under `app/assets/javascripts` will compress and minified to `application.js` in production.

```
$(function(){
  $('#preview-button').click(function () {
    alert("Preview button was clicked");
  });
})
```

Comment: It doesn't show me the alert when I press the button. By default, there is no phrases folder after app/assets/javascripts. I made phrases folder and made phrase.js in it.

Comment: Thank you richfisher. It is working now. user3506853 had explain how to include the js files in the phrases folder.